# TCP server - Range requests not getting sustained (HLS loopback server)

Tags: ios, c, sockets, http-live-streaming, tcpserver

I understand that Byte-Range support is expected of any HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) server.

We are serving media files in our iOS app through a localhost/loopback server using sockets in C, fgets to read data and fprintf to write back.

(Requirement of using a loopback server is immutable)

We use an MPMoviePlayerController for playback and it first sends and accepts range request/responses correctly. For example, the first set of request/responses are:

`Request 1

GET /internal_path/index.m3u8 HTTP/1.1

Host: 127.0.0.1:9019

Range: bytes=0-1

X-Playback-Session-Id: 454D2A01-2113-457A-AA6B-9AC841B37D2E

Accept-Encoding: identity

Accept: /

Accept-Language: en-us

Connection: keep-alive

User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.10A403 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X; en_us)




Response 1

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Content-Range: bytes 0-1/338

Content-Type: application/x-mpegURL

Content-Length: 2

Connection: keep-alive




Request 2

GET /internal_path/index.m3u8 HTTP/1.1

Host: 127.0.0.1:9019

Range: bytes=0-337

X-Playback-Session-Id: 454D2A01-2113-457A-AA6B-9AC841B37D2E

Accept-Encoding: identity

Accept: /

Accept-Language: en-us

Connection: keep-alive

User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.10A403 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X; en_us)`

**Response 2**

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Content-Range: bytes 0-337/338

Content-Type: application/x-mpegURL

Content-Length: 338

Connection: keep-alive

However, in spite of the server sending proper Range responses to the requests, subsequent requests for the index.m3u8 and for the TS files omit the Range header.

Is there some data missing from the headers being sent in the Response, which could cause the player to believe the localhost server does NOT support Range requests? Is something just plain wrong, that I'm not seeing?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not compare to some working streaming server?

Comment: One thing I've been comparing against is the results for MP4 streaming available here http://stevebranding.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/avplayer-in-depth/. M3U8 behavior maybe different, but until I find another authoritative source (or implement a separate, standard file serving server and test to compare) this would have to do.

Comment: Hi Dev Kanchen, I'm stuck at the same scenario where the requirement for loopback server is immutable. I'm also getting the first 2 requests as mentioned by you but after that I'm getting unsupported url error in the  Mpmovieplayercontroller. Can you please help me about how you solved the error and got it to work?

Comment: @Madala, unfortunately the requirement got dropped sometime after my asking the question. I didn't get the opportunity to solve it nor do I have access to the code anymore. I have kept this question open in the hope someone might be able to solve it. Sorry for not being able to help and for the late response.